# SQL INSERT if username doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

what is wrong with this query:

```
INSERT INTO `customers`(`username`, `password`) 
            VALUES (:username, :password)
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT `username` FROM `customers` WHERE `username`=:username
            );
```

Comment: What is your database ? Oracle or SQLServer or... ?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Shouldn't you be telling us what is wrong with it...? What happens when you run it? Why is that wrong? What should happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the query?  It generates a syntax error.

If you want to prevent duplicates, then use a unique constraint on the table:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD CONSTRAINT unq_customers_username UNIQUE (username);
```

Then if you attempt to insert a duplicate value using

```
INSERT INTO `customers`(`username`, `password`) 
     VALUES (:username, :password);
```

You will get an error of a constraint violation.

Often in this case, you want to actually *update* the password in the existing row.  You can do that using the MySQL extension `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO `customers`(`username`, `password`) 
     VALUES (:username, :password)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password = :password;
```